# Keep rows checked in Lightning-datatable

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, search, pagination

Hello guys I have a Lightning-datatable that allows me pagination and a search.

Until now I can select rows from any page in the datatable. The problem comes when the user inputs some name and check the options that appears with the filter. When he deletes what he wrote in the search box the previous data that was checked becomes unchecked.

For example. My lightning datatable has 7 pages and the user checks 5 rows in the first page and then from the second page he marks 4 rows. In total I have 9 checked rows. Then, for example, the user search a name to filter and then two records are left in the lightning datatble so, he checks only one of them. Next, the user deletes what he has wrote, the filter is gone and all the data appears again with the 7 pages of the lightning datatable but neither the 9 rows are checked nor the filter option he checked from the filter.

My code is here: https://app.lwc.studio/edit/6eJ7UenigPwcQU31iTos/src/app.js?p=stories

Could some one help me to keep the data stored when the user clears the search box?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've already actually [written](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/88mc3Gx8E4OZNksS14kZ/src/app.html?p=stories) something like this. This version doesn't include filtering, but that doesn't matter, because it demonstrates the core mechanic that makes this work: you only update the selected items that are visible, and retain the others in memory.

First, we keep track of all rows, the current page rows, the globally selected list of rows, and the current page rows:

```
  // All existing rows
  allData = []
  // All selected Id values
  allSelectedRows = new Set()
  // Current page index
  pageNumber = 0
  // Current page data rows
  pageData = []
  // Current page selected Id values
  selectedRows = []
```

Then, when a row is selected or deselected, we update the global state by using the new list of selected rows from the current page:

```
  selectRow(event) {
    // Id values for current page
    const pageIds = this.pageData.map(row => row.id)
    // Id values that are now selected on current page
    const selectedIds = new Set(event.detail.selectedRows.map(row => row.id))
    // Deselect all page id values from global Set
    pageIds.forEach(pageId => this.allSelectedRows.delete(pageId))
    // And add in this page's selected values
    selectedIds.forEach(pageId => this.allSelectedRows.add(pageId))
    this.updatePage()
  }
```

Where we first get all known ID and selected ID values from the current page. Then, we remove all known ID values from the globally selected set, and then add the selected ID values from the current page into the global set. Even though this code doesn't specifically address filtering, the algorithm will work no matter what you do to the current page, including filtering and sorting. If you remove values from the global data set, then you'll also want to remember to remove those ID values from the global selected set. Unfortunately, your demo from lwc.studio doesn't work, and appears incomplete, so I can't fix your code, but comparing your code to my own should help you, I think.

Comment: Hello @sfdcfox I tried applying the same approach you mentioned but it did not made any change. Could you try applying it to my code? I don`t see where could be the error and some mistake of mine.

Comment: @TechGuy I did try to fix your lwc.studio example, but it was completely non-functional. You had the template in the wrong file, a directive on a top-level template (that's illegal), some of the variables didn't line up, etc. At the time I wrote this answer, I was pre-coffee. I guess I can give it another try. I'll get back to you shortly.

Comment: @TechGuy try [this](https://app.lwc.studio/edit/4itB6uKlG6N9BjTatjoc/src/app.html?p=stories). I had to clean up quite a bit a logic, but I think this should get you started.

Comment: I updated the whole code I had to share the whole code not the part because its complex. If you could continue helping me I would appreciate it. Thanks